# Отображение текущего и конечного значения у SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar

Начал пытаться разработать свой Android плеер. Для перемотки музыки на какой-то определенный момент планирую использовать `SeekBar`. Однако интересен следующий момент: можно ли каким-то образом при помощи встроенных методов `SeekBar` отображать значения текущего момента песни и всей ее длительности. Вот пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, текущее значение - 0.23, а длительность - 52.05. Или для каждого значения следует создавать `TextView` и там уже отображать? И вообще, насколько правильно использовать в данном случае SeekBar? Может существует какой-то более подходящий вариант?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, а разве в `ProgressBar`  можно вручную установить значение? т.е в моем случае, вручную перейти к определенному моменту.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, возможно сейчас очень сильно туплю, но не могу понять: как пользователь сможет передвинуть ползунок на `ProgressBar`. Для `SeekBar` это понятно, но ведь на `ProgressBar` ползунка, который можно передвинуть, нету.

Comment: м, да, вы правы, для этой задачи тогда лучше `SeekBar`+2 `TextView` )

Comment: @Jarvis_J, тогда наверное оформите это как ответ, а я приму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте 2 `TextView` и `SeekBar` в горизонтальном `LinearLayout`, примерно вот так:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/currentTime"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mySeekbar" //ваш сикбар
        android:thumb="@drawable/myThumb"              //ваш ползунок (можно @null)
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fullTime"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```